# ActionBar Search button opening new activity

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

I have a Main Activity which displays Action bar with search option.
When user selects search icon, edit box to enter a search string is displayed.
When user enters search string and hits the search button, then a new activity is launched which receives this search string and then it performs the search.

This activity is also having the same search action bar on the top and user can re-enter the search term.

But problem is, every time user enters text and hit search, a new search activity is opened. What I want is, it should pass the new search term to the same activity as user is in the search activity.

Also how can I restore state of the main activity action bar, and hide the search edit text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple fragments in the same activity. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: Can adding fragment will solve this issue? How to use fragments in this action bar search scenario, as we mention activity that is going to take action on the search string in the manifest file. and android framework take cares of launching the search result activity.

Comment: Are you doing something similar to this [action-bar-search](http://www.edumobile.org/android/action-bar-search-view)

Comment: shailesh, Yes i am doing something similar, is it that we just need to implement  "SearchView.OnQueryTextListener" and it sends all the queries to our activity? this link does not provide all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` into your Intent when starting Search Activity, and there will be only one ins

Comment: I am not starting this activity, android framework is starting this activity. so i can't add this flag while starting the search activity.